# How do you position a div (with child divs) horizontally centered on the page?

Tags: html, css, margin, center, positioning

I'd like to center a div horizontally on the page (the div contains four gauge like radial dials that need to be next to each other and not one line after the other). My current CSS (below) displays the gauges next to each other so the float property seems to work fine but the margin property I have set for the parent div (allgauges) doesn't seem to be effective. Does the fact that I have several divs inside of "allgauges" make a difference when I try to align it to the center of the page? Any help is appreciated.

```css
<!-- Embedded style sheet to change the margin spacing between the gauges -->
    <style>
     
     
    #one, #two, #three, #four
    {
 float: left;
 }
  
    #allgauges
    {
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
        
    </style>
```

Comment: The snippet doesn't include the html

Comment: To center #allgauges div you must set his width in px or %

Comment: Setting the width worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered multiple times. Here is the solution:

```css
.one,.two, .three,.four
{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:25%;
  text-align:center; /* This is not necessary.*/
  font-size:13px;
}
  
.allgauges
{
   font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="allgauges">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
  <div class="four">4</div>
</div>
```